# Why do I need to reregister DLLs?

Tags: windows-7, disk-cloning

I recently cloned a partition with **Windows 7** on it. Hoping that it would work fine, I booted it successfully and was able to get it running except that I got something like "**Interface Not Supported**" when running some applications and **.NET** was reported to be missing on some programs.

I googled and found that it had something to do with "**Registering DLLs**". So, my question- When I cloned the partition on my hard disk, wasn't a perfect copy of it created. If so then why did I need to 'register DLL's again'. If not, explain.

Comment: Did the drive (i.e. system partition) letter change?

Comment: @Karan Yes, does that have to do anything?

Comment: @Karan LOL, that included explorer.exe

Comment: So, if I cloned it to a new partition with same drive letter. It would have worked without the need to reregister the DLLs ?

Comment: @Karan I think it was some DLL. After reregistering, explorer works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the system partition's drive letter changes after the cloning process, any apps that rely on hard-coded paths to DLLs and other files will naturally break. There are APIs such as GetWindowsDirectory(), SHGetKnownFolderPath(), SHGetSpecialFolderPath(), Environment.GetFolderPath() etc. that programmers should use but sometimes don't.

Also, apps that for licensing/piracy prevention reasons store the GUID of the volume they are installed on might break too. There is no easy fix in such cases except to re-register the app if possible.